# How to logout when copy url and paste it in same browser tab?

Tags: php

My problem is - after successfully login, if I copy the url and paste it into same browser tab then it should be move into logout page, due to security reason.

Comment: So, you want to kill the whole concept of sessions ?

Comment: Just don't use sessions. But be aware that you're not doing this for any legit security reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code on login page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login']='true';
```

Use this code on other page:

```
$check=$_SESSION['login'];
if($check !='true')
{
 //redirect to logout page
}
unset($_SESSION['login']);
```

Comment: I think you would need to read the question back. OP actually wants no session behaviour...